# about allocating ip address with dhcp of neutron

Tags: openstack

I created a vm in horizon, I use dhcp server of neutron to allocate IP and the following is the horizon show:

[image]

But in my vm console,it display:

[image]

so i want to know why it don't have an ip address?

Answer (score 0):

Check out neutron logs, it should give some clues. Mostly the log file will be located in /var/log folder of neutron host.

Probably you should also check for "dnsmasq" related logs and errors in /var/log/ folders

Comment: thanks! i will check it ! i find more error,vm can't ping gateway